# How to auto-update matching html/xml tag in Code Mirror

Tags: codemirror

I really like how Visual Studio html editor updates the matching tag. Example:

`<h2>Header</h2>`

If we replace `<h2>` opening tag with `<h3>`, then the closing tag should change automatically to `</h3>`. This should happen as we type.

I'm trying to implement this on my own, but no luck so far. I thought that matchtags addon would be a good starting point, but it stops working if tag names do not match.
Also, I noticed that xml mode marks closing tag as error on tag name mismatch, but I'm not sure how to use this to update the closing tags.

I would appreciate any help from more experienced CodeMirror users.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So once the edit has been *done*, you no longer have the information needed to find the matching tag (which is why the matchtag addon can't help anymore). A good solution might be to track the current matching tag when editing starts (when the cursor is in a tag name) by using the `CodeMirror.findMatchingTag` function exported by the `addon/fold/xml-fold.js` file. Then, on `"change"` events that look like local editing inside the tag name (i.e. their start and end are inside the tag name), immediately follow up by modifying the matching tag.

Answer (score 0):

add  matchtags.js, xml-fold.js

config : `matchTags: {bothTags: true}`